# ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts:15:21 - error TS2339: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Olá, 
Estou criando um projeto de autenticação com ionic e firebase, porém me deparei com este erro e não consigo resolver. Até o momento o aplicativo está apenas realizando os metodos register e login.[image: a propriedade auth está com erro.]

Answer (score 1):

Depois de configurar o AngularFire e injetar o AngularFireAuth você já pode usar os métodos. Sem a necessidade desse `.auth`.

```js
 constructor(
    private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  async doLogin(user): Promise<void> {
      await this.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    }catch(e) {
      alert('Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)')
    }  
  }
```

No seu exemplo seria algo como

```js
...

login(user){
   return this.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
}

...
```

Comment: Realmente... removi o .auth e a aplicação rodou normalmente.